# Unable to assign values using df.loc: df.loc["condition A"] = df.loc["condition B"] is not working

Tags: pandas, dataframe

the df.loc in the following line of code does not seem to working. Any idea why? The print statements before confirm that the df.loc is working and is also returning the same number of rows in both. But the value assignment is not happening. Thanks in advance.

```
print(df.loc[df['type'] == "OPEN", "A"])
print(df.loc[df['type'] == "CLOSE", "new"])
df.loc[df['type'] == "CLOSE", "new"] = df.loc[df['type'] == "OPEN", "A"]
print(df.loc[df['type'] == "OPEN", "A"])
print(df.loc[df['type'] == "CLOSE", "new"])
```

Result:

19    25790.00092
42    25565.00053
Name: trade_amount, dtype: float64
26    0
45    0
Name: new, dtype: int64
19    25790.00092
42    25565.00053
Name: trade_amount, dtype: float64
26   NaN
45   NaN

Answer (score 0):

Based on the provided code and the output, it seems that the issue lies in the assignment statement. The problem is related to mismatched indices between the rows where the values should be assigned. This discrepancy can happen when the indices of the rows in the 'OPEN' and 'CLOSE' groups do not match.

To fix this issue, you should ensure that the indices are aligned correctly when assigning values from one group to another. One way to do this is by resetting the index for both groups before performing the assignment. Here's how you can modify the code:

```
# Reset the indices for both 'OPEN' and 'CLOSE' groups
df_open = df.loc[df['type'] == "OPEN", "A"].reset_index(drop=True)
df_close = df.loc[df['type'] == "CLOSE", "new"].reset_index(drop=True)

# Assign the values with aligned indices
df.loc[df['type'] == "CLOSE", "new"] = df_open

# Print the results
print(df.loc[df['type'] == "OPEN", "A"])
print(df.loc[df['type'] == "CLOSE", "new"])
```

By resetting the indices with reset_index(drop=True), the assignment should work correctly, and you should see the desired output.